# Why Math.pow(a, b) is NaN when a is a negative number and b is a non-integer?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I observed the following Javascript behavior:

```
> Math.pow(4, 2)
16
> Math.pow(4, 2.1)
18.37917367995256
> Math.pow(4, 0.5)
2
> Math.pow(-4, 2)
16
> Math.pow(-4, 2.1)
NaN
> Math.pow(-4, 0.5)
NaN
```

Why giving a negative number and a non-integer but rational number, makes `Math.pow` to return `NaN`?

For example, why `Math.pow(4, 0.5)` is **not** `NaN` but `Math.pow(4, -0.5)` **is** `NaN`?

Comment: `Math.pow(-4, 0.5)` would be `2i` wouldn't it?

Comment: The result is an [imaginary number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_number). That's why.

Comment: I wonder how someone can be surprised about a result for which they had no idea on what to expect it to be. In other words: if you didn't know about complex numbers, what did you *expect* to be returned?

Comment: @IngoBürk *I wonder how* some people can not be surprised about anything... :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[Imaginary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_number) ([Complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number)) Number Alert!**

I have got a crazy result too. So what I have here is the same logic in different programming languages.

What I feel is, when the power is calculated, the resulting number is root of -1, which is an **imaginary number**. These programs cannot handle imaginary numbers is my guess.

---

The **results** are as follows:

**C#**

```
Math.Pow(-1.1, -1.1);    // Returns NaN
```

**Java** [Output](http://ideone.com/8enKS8)

```
Math.pow(-4, 2.1);      // Returns NaN
```

**JavaScript**

```
Math.pow(-4, 2.1);      // Returns NaN
```

Answer (score 5):

Because you've tried to compute a number that is not real. For example no real number is the solution to -4 to the power of 0.5. And so there comes the world of **[IMAGINARY NUMBERS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number)**.

You will get the best answer when you will see that [ECMAscript specification](http://es5.github.io/#x15.8.2.13) seems to say so.

Returns an implementation-dependent approximation to the result of raising x to the power y.

> **15.8.2.13 pow (x, y) # Ⓣ Ⓡ**
>
> - If y is NaN, the result is NaN.
> - If y is +0, the result is 1, even if x is NaN.
> - If y is −0, the result is 1, even if x is NaN.
> - If x is NaN and y is nonzero, the result is NaN.
> - If abs(x)>1 and y is +∞, the result is +∞.
> - If abs(x)>1 and y is −∞, the result is +0.
> - If abs(x)==1 and y is +∞, the result is NaN.
> - If abs(x)==1 and y is −∞, the result is NaN.
> - If abs(x)<1 and y is +∞, the result is +0.
> - If abs(x)<1 and y is −∞, the result is +∞.
> - **If x < 0 and x is finite and y is finite and y is not an integer, the
>     result is NaN.**
>
> .......................

Answer (score 0):

It's due to mathematics. Your value would be an imaginary number (complex numbers) which is not supported. :)