# Not sure how to use Math.pow()

Tags: java

I am new to Java. I am writing a small program to calculate the value of a number raised to a power, when I ran into a problem with negative numbers raised to a fractional exponent.

```
System.out.println(Math.pow(-8, 1/3f));
```

The output is NaN while I'm expecting -2?

What am I doing wrong? Are there any alternatives to calculate problems like this?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This gets a Complex number. Hence It gives NaN. Read [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250453/why-math-powa-b-is-nan-when-a-is-a-negative-number-and-b-is-a-non-integer)

Comment: I am expecting (-2)^3=-8, so answer is -2?

Comment: In this case it could return a real number that would be correct, but in general the result space for `(-n)^(1/m)` would be some set of complex numbers, so the spec says that it should consistently just return NaN.

Comment: how can I get a real value if possible?

Comment: Depends what you are actually trying to do. If it is to find out the cube root of `-8`, just assign `-2`. If it is to find out the cube root of _any_ negative number, then you can negate the cube root of the positive number. If it is to find any power of two numbers, you may be out of luck.

Comment: thanks khelwood. I am trying to get result for any two numbers, but guess there is no other way. I understand now, thanks a lot.

Comment: Actually `1/3f` is not 1/3, just a very close number to it, so it cannot be used that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This case is described in [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-) .

> If the first argument is finite and less than zero. <...>
>   if the second argument is finite and not an integer, then the result is NaN.

As far as I know there is no method in Java standard library to do it, so you have to implement it manually.

Comment: thanks. I guess I'll have to split two cases for positive and negative bases?

Comment: Yes, but anyway finding power with negative base seems to be not a trivial issue.